# Using CollectionAssert.Contains against a collection

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I want to write something like:

```
var list = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
var bigList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

CollectionAssert.Contains(bigList, list);
```

I can get an error similar to:

```
 Expected: collection containing < 1,2,3 >
 But was:  < 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 >
```

Is it possible to use the contains method against another collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature is

```
   CollectionAssert.Contains (ICollection collection, Object element)
```

And it checks if `element` (singular) is inside `collection`.
It is not a method to check for sub-lists.

You should probably use:

```
    CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf (ICollection subset, ICollection superset)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms243713%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Use `CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf`:

```
var list = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
var bigList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(list, bigList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same functionality, different syntax (NUnit's constraint style, closer to natural language, which is a quality of a good test):

```
var list = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
var bigList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

Assert.That( list, Is.SubsetOf( bigList ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using `CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(list, bigList)` is most often that you want to see which of the items from list is not included in the bigList. Testing that all items from `list` is contained in `bigList` only return true or false, which doesn't give me any helpful debugging information of what is wrong. I want the test to fail and also give the information which of the items was not in `bigList`.

So for me, I always convert the statement `CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(list, bigList)` to

```
var list = new List<int>(){0,1,2,3,9}; // note the 0 and 9 is added to the list
var bigList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

CollectionAssert.IsEmpty(list.Except(bigList));
```

Which gives the result

```
Expected <empty>
But was: <0, 9>
```

In other words, `list` contains 0 and 9, which are not contained in `bigList`

Comment: CollectionAssert.IsEmpty defined in NUnit, not MSTest